# Ray cast Turret only lands hits on enemies within a certain period of time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When shooting, my turret will register hits on enemies for about 4 seconds and then stop and never register any more hits, I have tried everything. I have found that the ray-cast will not hit enemies with the enemy layer at all after the given time and that applies to all enemies loaded in the world.

I have tried everything, here is my turret code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TurretController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;
    public float fireRate = 1f;
    public GameObject projectilePrefab;
    public Transform projectileSpawnPoint;
    public Transform RotationPoint;
    public float maxZoom = 12.75f;
    public float minZoom;
    public float ZoomScale;
    public Camera TurretCam;
    public float ZoomLevel;
    public float damage;
    public LayerMask hitMask;

    public bool isPlayerInTurret = false;
    private float timeSinceLastShot = 0f;

    void Update()
    {
        if (!isPlayerInTurret) TurretCam.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        if (isPlayerInTurret)
        {
            TurretCam.gameObject.SetActive(enabled);
            // Get input
            float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
            float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

            // Zoom level for turret camera
            float input = Input.mouseScrollDelta.y * ZoomScale * Time.deltaTime;
            ZoomLevel = Mathf.Clamp(input + ZoomLevel, maxZoom, minZoom);
            TurretCam.fieldOfView = ZoomLevel;



            // Rotate turret
            RotationPoint.Rotate(Vector3.up * horizontal * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            RotationPoint.Rotate(Vector3.right * -vertical * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Quaternion rotation = RotationPoint.transform.rotation;
            rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation.eulerAngles.x, rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0f);
            RotationPoint.transform.rotation = rotation;

            // Shoot
            timeSinceLastShot += Time.deltaTime;
            //if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && timeSinceLastShot >= 1f / fireRate)
            if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
            {
                print("click");
                timeSinceLastShot = 0f;
                RaycastHit hit;
                Debug.DrawLine(projectileSpawnPoint.transform.position, projectileSpawnPoint.transform.forward*1000, Color.red, 20f);
                if (Physics.Raycast(TurretCam.transform.position, TurretCam.transform.forward, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, hitMask))
                {
                    print("Ray has hit");
                    print(hit.collider.TryGetComponent<Enemy>(out Enemy enemy) + hit.transform.gameObject.name);
                    if (enemy != null)
                    {
                        enemy.takeDamage(damage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Enter/exit turret
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            /// TODO
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my enemy code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Objective;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;
    public float health = 100f;
    public GameObject explosion;
    public Vector3 ExplosionAdd;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        agent = gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().enabled = true;
        transform.parent = null;
    }
    bool hasExploded = false;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (hasExploded) return;
        //agent.destination = Objective.transform.position;
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == "Explode!") Explode();
    }

    public void takeDamage(float damage)
    {
        print("x");
        health -= damage;
    }
    public void Explode()
    {
        hasExploded = true;
        Objective.GetComponent<Objective>().TakeDamage(100);
        GameObject x = Instantiate(explosion, null);
        x.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position + ExplosionAdd;
        Destroy(x, 2);

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458248/physics-raycast-not-hit-sometimes) related thread help? Additionally, you can look at [this](https://discussions.unity.com/t/raycasting-stops-working-randomly/248330) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I reverted to my last working version and re-wrote everything from there, the code was the exact same. I assume my issue had to do with some configuration setting I had accidentally messed with. Good Luck!